# Empty HTML of droppable/sortable element on draggable stop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jQuery UI to draggable and sortable to create a drag and drop form builder. When the user stops dragging I want the droppable area to be empty because I am using a function that repopulates the droppable area.

I have tried using jQuery empty() in draggable stop event

```
let initDrag = () => {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".droppable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        stop: afterDrop
    })
}
let initSortable = () => {
    $( ".droppable" ).sortable({
        revert: true
    });
}

let afterDrop = (event, ui) => {
    let fieldID = $(event.target).attr("data-id")
    $(formTag).html(""); //This is where the problem is
    getFieldData(fieldID).then(fieldData => {
        fieldData[0].field.field_id = Date.now();
        formBuildingJSON.form_fields.push(fieldData[0]);
        appendFieldsMarkup()
    })
    $(ui.helper[0]).remove()
}
```

I am expecting the 2nd line of afterDrop() to empty the form tag. bu it is giving me an error.

`

> jquery-ui.js:16692 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'removeChild' of null
>       at $.(/form-builder/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._clear
>   (http://localhost/form-builder/external-scripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:16692:36)
>       at $.(/form-builder/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._clear
>   (http://localhost/form-builder/external-scripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:144:25)
>       at HTMLLIElement. (jquery-ui.js:15688)
>       at HTMLLIElement.r.complete (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at u (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at u (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Function.w.fx.tick (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at at (jquery.min.js:2)`

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zainulabd786/m2sp1zft/6/) of similar problem

Comment: Can you make any pen or fiddle for betterment?

Comment: okay let me try

Comment: @RohitMittal please check jsfiddle I added to question

Comment: it is making #sortable empty but it is also throwing an error. So want to avoid that error??

Comment: Yes. Because that error stops the execution of code

Comment: I am not sure if it helps you properly. but you can try with this: let afterDrop = (event, ui) => {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#sortable").html('');
                    }, 500);
                };. Also to check further, you can check these links: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6054

Comment: Yes this helps prevent the error, but couldn't solve the problem because I am clearing the HTML so that I can put fresh content in the `div` but setTimeout is async function and it removes my fresh content too

Comment: Then can't you put your fresh content on settimeout callback function. Means you will add fresh content after settimeout function executed. I feel this is not the right approach but may be it helps you to achieve your requirements.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. but sometimes that too breaks. because if js execution takes more time than the time that we have passed in setTimeout. it breaks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188516/discussion-between-rohit-mittal-and-waeez).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to make modification in your jquery-ui.js file. There is a line with below text:

```
this.placeholder[ 0 ].parentNode.removeChild( this.placeholder[ 0 ] );
```

Which you need to replace with below code:

```
if (this.placeholder[ 0 ].length) {
    if (this.placeholder[ 0 ].parentNode.length) {
         this.placeholder[ 0 ].parentNode.removeChild( this.placeholder[ 0 ] );                        
    }
}
```

Hope this code helps you.